# What's the measure of the segment HC in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In triangle $ABC$, in $AC$ the point $H$ is considered.
By $H$, the perpendicular $PH$ to $AC$ is drawn which intersects $AB$ at $Q$.
$PAB=53^o, \angle ACB =143^o$
$AP=AB, AH=12$
Calculate HC. (Answer:8)

My progress...
I think this is the drawing...I identified a menelaus in the triangle $ABC-QP \implies BQ.12.CP = QA.HC.PB$

but it didn't help much...
$\triangle PAB(isosceles) PA = PB \implies \angle P = \angle B$

Through geogebra I couldn't make the drawings according to the data provided... if I follow the data and the answer, the angles will not be the same,,, either I drew wrong or the problem is in the statement

[image] drawing is not to scale...

Figure mentioned by colleague Ivan:

[image]

Comment: Do we know that angel of $APH$? Is that angel colored orange because it is $53^\circ$? If so, first solve for $HP$ and then for $HC$.

Comment: @ACB I also found it...but I only post the question as an exact copy of the book...I For me,  $H \in AC$ and $AH = 12\\PQ \perp AC, Q \in AB, ~and ~P \in PB ~and ~AP=AB $.

Comment: But what about angles? You write $PAB=53^\circ, \angle 143^\circ$. Which angle is $53$ and which is $143$ as per the question?

Comment: @MathLover    forgive my distraction...I've already made the correction..$\angle PAB = 53^o$, ~ $\angle ACB = 143^o$  and redid the figure

Comment: Also, is it $PA = AB$ or $PA = PB$? The question says $PA = AB$ but your work says $PA = PB$ and corresponding angles.

Comment: @MathLover  PA = AB... see that in the drawing I have already corrected the relationships

Comment: @MathLover The drawing is not to scale...With the data provided, I couldn't make the drawing to scale..so I think there is a problem with the statement

Comment: Yes it is not possible. The question seems to have a mistake.

Comment: @MathLover  that's what i thought..thank you for the confirmation

Comment: @MathLover...I think Ivan  unlocked the "secret"..see the new drawing..I think it is now possible to solve by geometry

Comment: Yes he did unlock it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many thanks to @Ivan for identifying the error in the original image, and here is a solution by geometry as per the request of OP.

[image: IMG]

Extend $\small PH$ to meet $\small BC$ extend at $\small G$. $\angle CGH=53^\circ$.

$\small \therefore\angle BGP=\angle BAP\implies AGBP\ \text{is cyclic}$

As $\small AB=AP$, $\small \angle ABP=63.5^\circ$, and so is $\small \angle AGP$ because they are in the same segment.

Therefore, $\small \triangle AHG$ is a special right triangle with perpendicular sides in the ratio 1:2.

$\small \therefore HG=6$

Similarly, as $\small \triangle CGH$ is a $\small 3:4:5$ right triangle, $\small HC=8$.

Comment: The answer is not precise 8, because tan(63.5°) is not precise 2.
The solution is not only by geometry, because you use trigonometrical fact tan(63.5°)≈2.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But as I know, the book that OP is referring to, always considers special right triangles as in my answer. Have a look at OP's past questions : ) E.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4234366/947379

Comment: Understood, but I think it is something wrong in avoiding trigonometry by using such tricks, that are still based on trigonometry.

Comment: @ACB  excellent...I'm glad Ivan realized where the error was.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not precise 8.

If you make drawing placing P up to AC.

$AH=AP \cos (53^o+\angle BAC) = AB \sin(37^o-\angle BAC)=AB \sin \angle ABC=AC \sin 143^o \Rightarrow AC=AH \csc 143^o \Rightarrow HC=AH(\csc 143^o-1)\approx 8$.

Comment: very good..I think you've unlocked the "secret"

Comment: would it be possible to have a resolution without trigonometry? .I imagine that maybe because of remarkable triangles depending on the angles that appear

Comment: Aha, makes sense now that I read it!